# $_GET cannot get the link value to generate qr code

Tags: php

I need to get the id inorder to generate the qr code, i used $_GET but i cant get it. Anyone can solve my problem?

A.php

```
foreach($viewids as $viewid){
$vid = $viewid->sequence;
echo '<img src="generateqrcode.php?id='.$vid"/></a>';
}
```

B.php

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$link = TARGET_LINK.$id;
QRcode::png($link,false,"L",10,0);
```

Comment: You have a space in ?id =

Comment: no sorry , code modified

Answer (score 2):

From what you have posted, your query string is not correctly formatted. Notice the space between `id` and `=` and also a syntax error.

```
foreach($viewids as $viewid){
    $vid = $viewid->sequence;
    echo '<img src="generateqrcode.php?id=' . $vid . '"/></a>';
}
```

Comment: With what you have `$vid` will not be parsed as a variable.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in A.php:

```
foreach($viewids as $viewid){
    $vid = $viewid->sequence;
    echo '<img src="generateqrcode.php?id ='.$vid"/></a>';
}
```

should be:

```
foreach($viewids as $viewid){
    $vid = $viewid->sequence;
    echo "<img src='generateqrcode.php?id=$vid'/></a>";
}
```

Comment: With what you have `$vid` will not be parsed as a variable.

Comment: @ProGM Thankyou! Why it is ?id=$vid instead of ?id ='.$vid.
The other part of the problem is , I cant get the value of $id in B.php

Comment: @user3118482 check [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#113932) for an explaination for `?id=$vid`. In B.php, try to make some debug. Add an `var_dump($_GET);` to your page in order to read the value of all passing parameters. (and add those results to your answer)

Answer (score 2):

replace:

```
echo '<img src="generateqrcode.php?id='.$vid"/></a>';
```

with:

```
echo "<img src='generateqrcode.php?id=$vid'/></a>";
```